# Php json_decode parsing read child value

Tags: php

I am parsing a JSON being posted from another website and one of the nodes has a child.

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input= json_decode( $inputJSON); //convert JSON into object

$order_number = $input->{'order_no'};
$name = $input->{'name'};
$street_address = $input->{'address_1'};
$city =$input->{'city'};
$state = $input->{'region'} ;
$zip = $input->{'postal_code'};
```

I am being able to read all the values. However, the product section has the format

```
<items>
    <product_code></product_code>
    <product_name></product_name>
</items>
```

I am trying to read it as

```
$product_id = $input->{'items'}{'product_code'};
$product_description = $input->{'items'}{'product_name'};
```

But I am getting no data in my variables. What is the correct syntax?

Thanks.

Edit: The JSON output

```
object(stdClass)#1 (20) {
  ["test_order"]=>
  string(1) "Y"
  ["shop_no"]=>
  string(6) "142319"
  ["order_no"]=>
  string(12) "TU5495467701"
  string(5) "Smith"
  ["city"]=>
  string(5) "Bosei"
  ["postal_code"]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  ["order_total"]=>
  string(5) "39.00"
  ["country"]=>
  string(2) "HK"
  ["telephone"]=>
  string(8) "12345678"
   ["pay_source"]=>
  string(2) "CC"
  ["base_currency"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (9) {
      ["product_price"]=>
      string(5) "39.00"
      ["product_name"]=>
      string(12) "Abcd Product"
      ["product_code"]=>
      string(8) "142319-1"
    }
  }
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(4) "John"
}
```

Comment: That is XML, not JSON. The real JSON may or may not look anything like that.

Comment: Added the JSON output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote:

```
["items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (9) {
      ["product_price"]=>
      string(5) "39.00"
      ["product_name"]=>
      string(12) "Abcd Product"
      ["product_code"]=>
      string(8) "142319-1"
    }
  }
```

The `items` element is an array, contains multiple objects, so you must use this syntax:

```
$product_id = $input->items[0]->product_code;
$product_description = $input->items[0]->product_name;
```

And, If the `items` are more than one, you should use a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($input->items); $i++) {
    $product_id = $input->items[$i]->product_code;
    $product_description = $input->items[$i]->product_name;
}
```

Comment: Either all are objects or all are arrays. You won't get this kind of nested array inside an object.

Comment: @deceze Yes, you are **exactly** right. I change my answer. Thank you `;)`.

Comment: Tried this: $product_id = $input->items->product_code;
$product_description = $input->items->product_name; but still blank.

Comment: NOX that worked superbly! Thanks. I could not vote because I am new and do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product_id = $input->items[0]->product_code;
```

More likely though you will want to *loop* through `$input->items` instead of directly accessing just the first index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure but I think you can use it as an array and do something like this:

```
$product_id = $input['items']['product_code'];
$product_description = $input['items']['product_name'];
```

Answer (score -2):

In php json_decode returns an array. So you should be able to access it simply as you access array values.

$product_id = $input['items']['product_code'];

Comment: Unless you set the `$assoc` argument to `true`, it returns objects.